# Storing Azure Log Analytics to an Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics

To overcome the limitation of X number of days before retention I rather want to store Log Analytics data to an Azure SQL Database instead. I see there are export possibilities, but I want to do this automatically. I can of course be scheduled for instance every 15 minute. If any of you has set up a solution for this I really want to hear how you did it. And of course with incremental load.

This data will be used for analytical purposes.

Regards Geir

Comment: I would suggest you to store data in storage account and query it using Azure Data Explorer. For more information, you can refer this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/azure-data-explorer-query-storage

Answer (score 0):

No, you are doing it wrong.

Or you are imagining it in the wrong way.

I give you two solutions:

- **If your goal is storing Logs:** Microsoft provides this solution which came out few weeks ago: [Compressing Audit log files on Azure Blob Storage using ADF Pipeline for Azure SQL Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/compressing-audit-log-files-on-azure-blob-storage-using-adf/ba-p/3740656) . This will make it much cheaper than storing logs on an Azure SQL Database.
- **If your goal is investigating Logs:** you should use [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/monitoring-sql-database-azure-monitor?view=azuresql) and query the logs through Kusto. Take for example [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323581/how-to-get-session-information-for-azure-sql-database-errors-via-kusto) that came out few hours ago. People use Kusto queries to dive into tons of logs.

Don't store your Azure SQL Database logs into a dedicate Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Thank you for a fast and impressive response on my question. I can further tell that my task is to create a data model that is generic for all kind of logs (and perhaps other types of capturing traces/metrics). My leader thinks this could grow connecting more applications and their logs. But I guess most of the Azure apps use Azure monitor which then can be extracted. I will test this. And I believe it does not matter if I am using Synapse workspace in stead of data factory :-)

Comment: a "data model that is generic for all kind of logs" exists already and it' called Azure Log Analytics. It also has the word "log" in it. Tell to your Leader that Azure SQL Database or Synapse will cost x5 or x10 time the price of Log Analytics.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. but what about the limitation of number of days before retention? It could be serverless and data lake as well...

Comment: Yes, it is serverless.... because it's not "running" like a VM or a database. You pay the size of the logs and it'a much cheaper than a Sorage or a Database.
Yes, it's a data lake.... because c'mon, you can store all logs from all resources that you have an Azure. That is quite vast.

Comment: Look, this is an example of how to use Log Analytics to query the logs of the whole park of Azure SQL Databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/monitoring-sql-database-azure-monitor?view=azuresql

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify. we will be using log analytics and connect it to all other azure tools we will be using and think is neccessary. Further to overcome the limitation of retention days we need to store the logs elsewhere. A blob could be a case, a azure sql database (datawarehouse version) or directly to a power bi dataset with incremental refresh. the logging from use of sql queries from synapse (serverless or spark) could be a case

Comment: Tell me about your "retention days". Because with Log Analytics you can set the retention from 1 to 6 years or even more. And there is also an auto archive.

Comment: Okay, here's a different related use case. Our company saves in Log Analytics for a period of a few weeks. On-prem, I'm using Event Notifications in SQL Server to save DDL changes to a database, and at this point I have years worth of history. Somebody deployed code 3 years ago and changed a table? I can tell you who, when, and even what program they used to make the change. I'm trying to figure out how to do that with LA, since EN isn't possible on Azure SQL DB.